# How do I design my application such that audit trails cannot be edited or deleted?

Tags: database, audit, audit-trail

I have this problem where I need audit trails (typically stored in DB) to be non-editable and deletable even for DBAs and System Admins.

1 way is to apply encryption and checksums, but this only allows detection of changes or prevention of snooping. It does not prevent a DBA to just delete a row.

Any discussion on this matter is appreciated.

Comment: If you can't trust your DBAs and System Admins, you have a *personnel* issue that can't be solved by programmatic means.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the audit trails to be non editable even by the DBAs and system admins, you would need to store them outside of equipment that is in their control.

However that would lead to the same problem - the DBAs and system admins of this system would be able to edit them.

The best bet is to have a system where you store these in two disparate locations that do not share an admin and have periodic comparision checks.

Alternatively you can have triggers on update/delete when they are made by a specific user or from a particular client. These triggers could be programmed to send email or text messages if such a non-application update or delete is made.

It should be known - very well known in the admin/dba community that such triggers exist. You wil not be able to prevent the updates or deletes but will definitely get them to stay away from that table.

There is still a catch however, which is the ability to remove or modify the trigger code.

Comment: Further to the above, you could hash the audit line, and have an audit check function that compares the two hashes - you could also post the hash from locationA to locationB and visa versa. That would give you an added checking layer.

Answer (score 1):

There exists "write-once" archival storage systems, such as [Venti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venti) from Plan 9. That doesn't stop anyone with physical access taking a magnet to the hard disk or similar of course ;)

A sufficiently savvy sysadmin could create a slightly modified version of the data and replace the reference to the venti score though... and an equally savvy sysadmin could still recover the original data.

Anyway, I think you could learn a lot from studying append-only storage systems. They make a lot of sense for storing audit trails, compared to a DB.

Answer (score 1):

There exists appliances that act as sniffers and are able to record every single command executed on the database. IBM Guardium is an example.